# Setting state to 0 if no checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

The grabData function gets me the values of the checked checkboxes and submits it to my data array.  What I am wanting to know is how can I set the `state` to `0` if no checked checkboxes are submitted - I would also like it to `alert` when none are selected - validation

```
   function grabData(checked){
        checked = typeof(checked) == 'undefined' ? false : checked;
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName('product_category_selector');
        var data  = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            if(items[i].type != 'checkbox' || items[i].checked != checked){
                 continue;
            }

            data.push(items[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
        }

        return data;
    }
                $('body').on("click", "#brands_by_category_submit_btn", function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();               
                    var self = $(this);
                    var box  = $("#catInfo"); 
                    var id = $("#manID").data("id");
                    var cat_id = grabData();

                    var url = $("#brands_by_category_submit_btn").data("url");

                    var data_array = { 
                            id : id, 
                            cat_id : grabData(true), 
                            state: 1
                        };

                            ajaxCall(url, data_array,'catInfo');

                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all you could greatly simplify your `grabData` function.

```
function grabData(checked) {
    return $('.product_category_selector' + (checked? ':checked' : ':not(:checked)')).map(function (index, chk) {
        return $(chk).data('id');
    }).get();
}
```

Then within the click handler you could do:

```
var data = grabData(true); //get checked checkbox data-id values

console.log(data.length); //if 0, no items were checked
```

Comment: Thanks the function was written by another SO member with `data.length` would I process that via an if statement if its = to 0?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Yes, exactly, however you do not have to check if it's explicitely equal to 0 since 0 is falsey in JavaScript which means `Boolean(0)` is `false`. Writing `if (0)` is the same as `if (Boolean(0))`, so you can simply do `if (data.length)`. The ternary operatory can be quite useful as well, for instance `var state = data.length? 1 : 0;` which will set the state to 0 when the length is 0 and 1 when it isin't.